# Providing a login form in default MVC header layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'd like to add a login form onto the default _Layout page of ASP.NET MVC 5.

Now while I do know how to include a partial page into my layout, one thing I'm struggling with is the model.

How can I add a model to my _Login view (residing in _Layout), but not to my other views? I'd need to switch it once the user is logged in, because I don't need it then.

And how can I redirect the user to my regular Login page once the login fails to display them some sort of model error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty trivial. You just need to use a child action. For simply rendering a form based on a model, all you'd need is something like in your `AccountController` class:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult HeaderLogin()
{
    var model = new LoginViewModel();
    return PartialView("_Login", model);
}
```

Then, in your layout just call the following where you want it to appear:

```
@Html.Action("HeaderLogin", "Account)
```

The only thing to keep in mind is that the form wrapping your login fields needs to have its `action` attribute set to the URL for your regular login page. Then, it will naturally feed into the standard login process, displaying the actual login page on error.

Comment: Awesome, didn't thought of that... This really is trivial. Can accept your answer in a few minutes :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: just noticed another answer, so my answer is like addition to it :)

It's a bit tricky to explain, but lett's split your question to subquestions:

**1) How to redirrect** use something like this:

```
var result = await mgr.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Login, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        ResetCaptchaCounter();
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        IncreaseCaptchaCounter();
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The account is locked, try again later.");
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        ResetCaptchaCounter();
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong login or password!");
        IncreaseCaptchaCounter();
        return View();
}
```

**2) How to add model to the _Login view...**

Why not to use same model? Anyway your partial view and real login view should contain same inputs...

**3) Switch partial view (login form) to show something else when user is logged in:**

1. check if user is authenticated
2. render some other partial view, like "Logout form"

Ask if there is something more u want to know, or if you want more detailed answer in some section.

Answer (score 0):

you can put partial view to the layout page like.

@Html.Partial("~/Views/UserControlls/BreadCrum.cshtml")

and you can also pass some modle to that partial view as well like .

@Html.Partial("~/Views/UserControlls/BreadCrum.cshtml",model)